# strsplit into a variable number of columns

Tags: r, for-loop, multiple-columns, split, strsplit

This is a follow-on to this question I asked earlier: [R for loop: create a new column with the count of a sub str from a different column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18881136/r-for-loop-create-a-new-column-with-the-count-of-a-sub-str-from-a-different-col)

I have a large table (100+ colums, 50k+rows). One of the columns contains data in the following format:

```
col
chicken
chicken,goat
cow,chicken,goat
cow
```

I want to get to:

```
col         col2         col3
chicken
chicken     goat
cow         chicken      goat
cow
```

There are many more than 3 columns that need to be filled, I just stripped this down to be an example. My script creates the appropriate number of columns to be filled, I just need the code, I assume it's a for loop, to split the string in 'col' on ',' and then place the split strings into the subsequent columns.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `strsplit` on the comma and then `plyr::rbind.fill`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
read.table(text="chicken
 chicken,goat
 cow,chicken,goat
 cow", fill=TRUE, sep=",")
# Trivial to change the names of dataframe columns
        V1      V2   V3
1  chicken             
2  chicken    goat     
3      cow chicken goat
4      cow
```

Comment: This is one of many compact and elegant solutions to problems that I learned from Gabor Grothendeick in the R-help mailing list. Working out why his numerous worked solutions to regex questions "worked" was how I learned regular expressions.

Comment: Here I feel stuck in thinking "oh, well the data is already in R (damage done), let's see what we can do to clean up", instead of - like in your answer - take one step back and present a more pro-active solution. Cool.

Comment: One could also take the `col1` vector and feed it to read.table(text=...) and then cbind() to the original dataframe.

Comment: ^^ This answer doesn't take anything from outside the `R` workspace even though it uses `read.table`, so it can be made to work even if the 'damage is done.'

Comment: @Señor O, thanks a lot for making things (even) clearer to me. So many nice tricks...Cheers.

Comment: @Henrik, if you look at the help page for `concat.split`, you'll see that I attributed my knowledge of this approach to DWin and have implemented it as the "compact" approach. However, there is a shortcoming to this approach that I have accounted for in `concat.split`: If the first 5 rows of a file have fewer fields than any of the subsequent rows, R wraps the data incorrectly. The solution I've used is to use `count.fields` first and create column names from that to force R to include the correct number of columns.

Comment: @Henrik, for an example, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18797675/r-read-table-loops-row-column-entries-to-next-row/18797893#18797893).

Comment: @Ananda Mahto, thanks a lot for your comments and the suggested reading. First five rows...yes...if I remember correctly you pointed me to `count.fields` in one of my previous answers. Good point. I really appreciate your feed-back. Thanks a lot and thanks for a great package.

Answer (score 3):

You may try this:

```
library(splitstackshape)
concat.split(data = df, split.col = 1, sep = ",", drop = TRUE)

#     col_1   col_2 col_3
# 1 chicken              
# 2 chicken    goat      
# 3     cow chicken  goat
# 4     cow
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I think their data includes some blank rows, and I didn't account for that in the version of "splitstackshape" that is on CRAN.

Comment: @Ananda Mahto, I was actually waiting two minutes extra to give you the opportunity to give the answer first. ;)